# WPF TreeView add custom Header to HierarchicalDataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I created a simple example that contains a list of classes and a list of students within the class. This gives a TreeView like this:

```
school
|-class1
  |-student1
  |-student1
|-class2
...
```

But what I want is a look like this:

```
school
|-CLASSES
  |-class1
    |-STUDENTS
      |-student1
      |-student1
  |-class2
  ...
```

I would like to do this without altering the objects bound to the TreeView. It would be perfect if I could add a custom (CLASSES, STUDENTS, etc...) naming somehow to each HierarchicalDataTemplate.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my basis:

**C#** Classses needed

```
public class School
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Classi> classes { get; set; }
    }
    public class Classi
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Student> students { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

**C#** List bound to TreeView

```
private List<object> _items = new List<object>();
        public List<object> items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => items);
            }
        }
```

**C#** Filling my school

```
var stud1 = new Student { name = "student1" };
var stud2 = new Student { name = "student2" };
var clas1 = new Classi { name = "class1" };
clas1.students = new List<Student>();
clas1.students.Add(stud1);
var clas2 = new Classi { name = "class2" };
clas2.students = new List<Student>();
clas2.students.Add(stud2);
var school = new School();
school.name = "school";
school.classes = new List<Classi>();
school.classes.Add(clas1);
school.classes.Add(clas2);
items.Add(school);
```

**XAML** The TreeView containing the HierarchicalDataTemplates

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding classes}" DataType="{x:Type src:School}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding students}" DataType="{x:Type src:Classi}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Student}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </DataTemplate >
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I ended up altering the data that is bound to the tree view. But if you managed to figure out how to solve your problem with HierarchicalDataTemplate, could you please post an answer here!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but since I was searching for an answer for a very similar problem, for the reference here's one possible (not very general) solution.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="studentTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="classesTemplate">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=name}" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="STUDENTS" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=students}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource studentTemplate}"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="schoolTemplate">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=name}" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="CLASSES" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=classes}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource classesTemplate}"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView Name="thisTree" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource schoolTemplate}" />
```

The solution is "inspired" by [this](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1401031/Using-the-WPF-Tree-View-with-Multiple-Levels) and [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/1000/how-do-i-bind-a-treeview-to-a-hierarchical-list-where-some-nodes-have-multiple-child-lists)